# Table x has no column y error. Searched and can't find working solution

Tags: android, sqlite

I'm building an Android app that will teach kids how to write. As such I need to save certain pieces of information about each child as well as their result with specific letter. I'm at the stage of building the database and have been using tutorials on Youtube but I'm getting a lot of errors:

```
1) table studentTable has no column named studentSchool
    Error inserting studentSurname=fdfsfdf studentSchool=fdfdfefe studentForname=gdgdfdf
    android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: table studentTable has no column named studentSchool (code 1): , while compiling: INSERT INTO studentTable(studentSurname,studentSchool,studentForname) VALUES (?,?,?)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativePrepareStatement(Native Method)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.acquirePreparedStatement(SQLiteConnection.java:882)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.prepare(SQLiteConnection.java:493)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteSession.prepare(SQLiteSession.java:588)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteProgram.<init>(SQLiteProgram.java:58)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteStatement.<init>(SQLiteStatement.java:31)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.insertWithOnConflict(SQLiteDatabase.java:1467)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.insert(SQLiteDatabase.java:1339)
        at com.example.letterwriter.Database.createStudentEntry(Database.java:153)
        at com.example.letterwriter.RegStudentActivity.register(RegStudentActivity.java:42)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
        at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3594)
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4204)
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:17355)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:725)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

The top error is my main prom at the moment. I've search and found a lot of people with similar problems but none of the solutions work for me. I'm beginning to wonder is there something else wrong that is preventing the other solutions from working.

```
private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "letterwriter"; // Database Name
private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 4; // Database Version  
private static final String TABLE_STUDENT = "studentTable";  // Student table name
private static final String TABLE_TEACHER = "teacherTable";  // Teacher table name
private static final String TABLE_RESULTS = "resultsTable";  // Results table name

//Student columns
private static final String KEY_sID = "studentId";
private static final String KEY_sSNAME = "studentSurname";
private static final String KEY_sFNAME = "studentForname";
private static final String KEY_sSCHOOL = "studentSchool";
private static final String KEY_t_ID = "teacherId";
private static final String KEY_t_SNAME = "teacherSurname";

//Teacher columns
private static final String KEY_tID = "teacherId";
//private static final String KEY_PW = "password";
private static final String KEY_tSNAME = "teacherSurname";
private static final String KEY_tFNAME = "teacherForename";
private static final String KEY_tSCHOOL = "teahcerSchool";

//Student columns
private static final String KEY_s_ID = "student id";
private static final String KEY_aRes = "A";
private static final String KEY_bRes = "B";
private static final String KEY_cRes = "C";
private static final String KEY_dRes = "D";
private static final String KEY_eRes = "E";
private static final String KEY_fRes = "F";
private static final String KEY_gRes = "G";
private static final String KEY_hRes = "H";
private static final String KEY_iRes = "I";
private static final String KEY_jRes = "J";
private static final String KEY_kRes = "K";
private static final String KEY_lRes = "L";
private static final String KEY_mRes = "M";
private static final String KEY_nRes = "N";
private static final String KEY_oRes = "O";
private static final String KEY_pRes = "P";
private static final String KEY_qRes = "Q";
private static final String KEY_rRes = "R";
private static final String KEY_sRes = "S";
private static final String KEY_tRes = "T";
private static final String KEY_uRes = "U";
private static final String KEY_vRes = "V";
private static final String KEY_wRes = "W";
private static final String KEY_xRes = "X";
private static final String KEY_yRes = "Y";
private static final String KEY_zRes = "Z";

private DbHelper dbHelp;
private final Context context;
private SQLiteDatabase dbase;


private class DbHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper{

    public DbHelper(Context con){
        super(con, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {

        db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS " + TABLE_STUDENT + " (" +
               KEY_sID + " INTEGER, " + 
               KEY_sSNAME + " TEXT NOT NULL, " + 
               KEY_sFNAME + " TEXT NOT NULL, " +
               KEY_t_ID + " INTEGER, " +
               KEY_t_SNAME + " TEXT NOT NULL, " +
               "FOREIGN KEY (" + KEY_t_ID + ") REFERENCES " + 
               TABLE_TEACHER + " (" + KEY_tID + "), " +
               "FOREIGN KEY (" + KEY_t_SNAME + ") REFERENCES " + 
               TABLE_TEACHER + " (" + KEY_tID + "), " +
               "PRIMARY KEY (" + KEY_sID + ", " + KEY_sSNAME + ", " + KEY_sFNAME + "));"
        );

        db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_TEACHER + " (" +
               KEY_tSNAME + " TEXT NOT NULL, " + 
               KEY_tFNAME + " TEXT NOT NULL, " + 
               KEY_tSCHOOL + " TEXT NOT NULL, " +
               "PRIMARY KEY (" + KEY_tSNAME + ", " + KEY_tFNAME + "));"
        );

        db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_RESULTS + " (" +
               KEY_aRes + " TEXT, " + KEY_bRes + " TEXT, " +
               KEY_cRes + " TEXT, " + KEY_dRes + " TEXT, " +
               KEY_eRes + " TEXT, " + KEY_fRes + " TEXT, " +
               KEY_gRes + " TEXT, " + KEY_hRes + " TEXT, " +
               KEY_iRes + " TEXT, " + KEY_jRes + " TEXT, " +
               KEY_kRes + " TEXT, " + KEY_lRes + " TEXT, " +
               KEY_mRes + " TEXT, " + KEY_nRes + " TEXT, " +
               KEY_oRes + " TEXT, " + KEY_pRes + " TEXT, " +
               KEY_qRes + " TEXT, " + KEY_rRes + " TEXT, " +
               KEY_sRes + " TEXT, " + KEY_tRes + " TEXT, " +
               KEY_uRes + " TEXT, " + KEY_vRes + " TEXT, " +
               KEY_wRes + " TEXT, " + KEY_xRes + " TEXT, " +
               KEY_yRes + " TEXT, " + KEY_zRes + " TEXT);"
        );
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_STUDENT);
        onCreate(db);
    }

}

public Database(Context c) {
    context = c;
}

public Database openForWrite() throws SQLException {
    dbHelp = new DbHelper(context);
    dbase = dbHelp.getWritableDatabase();

    return this;
}

public Database openForRead() {
    dbHelp = new DbHelper(context);
    dbase = dbHelp.getReadableDatabase();

    return this;
}

public void close(){
    dbHelp.close();
}

long createStudentEntry(String f, String surname, String school ){
    ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
    cv.put(KEY_sFNAME, f);
    cv.put(KEY_sSNAME, surname);
    cv.put(KEY_sSCHOOL, school);

    //find way to do insert where
    return dbase.insert(TABLE_STUDENT, null, cv);
}

//look into password issue
long createTeacherEntry(String forename, String surname, String school ){
    ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
    cv.put(KEY_tFNAME, forename);
    cv.put(KEY_tSNAME, surname);
    cv.put(KEY_tSCHOOL, school);

    //find way to do insert where
    return dbase.insert(TABLE_TEACHER , null, cv);
}

long createResultEntry(String key, String result ){
    ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
    cv.put(key, result); // may not work change later

    //find way to do insert where?
    return dbase.insert(TABLE_STUDENT , null, cv);
}

public String getData(){
    String [] columns = new String []{KEY_sFNAME, KEY_sSNAME, KEY_sSCHOOL};
    Cursor c = dbase.query(TABLE_STUDENT, columns, null, null, null, null, null);
    String queryRes = "";

    int sFName = c.getColumnIndex(KEY_sFNAME);
    int sSName = c.getColumnIndex(KEY_sSNAME);
    int sSCHOOL = c.getColumnIndex(KEY_sSCHOOL);

    for(c.moveToFirst(); !c.isAfterLast(); c.moveToNext()){
        queryRes = queryRes + c.getString(sFName) + " " + c.getString(sSName) + " " + c.getString(sSCHOOL) + "\n";
    }
    c.close();

    return queryRes;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `onCreate` method, in the sql string used to create the `TABLE_STUDENT` you don't declare a column with a name corresponding to `KEY_sSCHOOL` which you use in the `createStudentEntry` method.

Double check that sql string and insert that column and after, either increment the database version or reinstall the app.

Comment: Thanks a lot. How is it I didn't see that for myself ?

Comment: @Unem Sometimes you just miss the obvious. It's always a good idea to take a step back, relax and then come back and try to solve the problem.